# Does current Google Drive Api give option similar to downloadUrl with access token in query string?

Tags: google-drive-api

Before January 1, 2020 Google Drive API allows to specify access token in query string. Therefore it was possible to get downloadUrl for video file in Google Drive, then to add access token as parameter in the query string and this url can be used as source url for html player in browser. Now in accordance with [changes to the Google Drive API](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api) this way does not work. The article recommends to use webContentLink but it seems they require cookies. Therefore if user is not logged into corresponding Google account the webContentLink cannot be used as source url for html player as instead of content of the file it returns Google page for login. If I share the file then webContentLink returns the file content but this variant is not acceptable for me. I know that it is possible to download file in browser memory and then to use data url. But this variant is not good for big video file as before playing all file has to be download.
Does Google Drive API offer at current moment an option similar to downloadUrl with access token in query string?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this workaround can be used for your actual situation, how about this? https://github.com/tanaikech/One_Time_Download_for_Google_Drive If this was not suitable for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I cannot use this in my case

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation.